# method extremum of function in java

Tags: java

I decided to calculate the extrema of the function by the Fibonacci method, I am a beginner, I encountered some errors in the code, if it isn`t difficult to help correctly write the code to determine the minimum and maximum, outputs -2, counted the result with the help of a gold section, turned out to be 1.55.

```
public class Fibonacci {
     double func(double x){
            return Math.pow(x,3)-26*x+6*Math.pow(x, 2)-9;
        } 
     double findMininFibonacci(double range_min_0, double range_min_1, double eps_min){
            double x1, x2;
            double N;   
            int j=10;
            int[] f = new int[j];
            f[0] = 1;
            f[1] = 1;
            f[3] = 2;
            f[4] = 3;
            double h_min;
            double x3;
            double x4;  
            while ((range_min_1-range_min_0)>eps_min){                  
                for (int i = 4; i < j; ++i) {
                    N = (range_min_1-range_min_0)/eps_min;
                  f[i] = f[i - 1] + f[i - 2];   
                  x1 = range_min_0 + (f[i-2]/f[i])*(range_min_1-range_min_0);
                  x2 = range_min_0 + (f[i-1]/f[i])*(range_min_1-range_min_0);               
                if(func(x1)<=func(x2)) {
                    range_min_1 = x2;
                    x2 = x1;
                    x1 = range_min_0 + (f[i-3]/f[i-1])*(range_min_1-range_min_0);
                } else {        
                    range_min_0 = x1;
                    x1 = x2;
                    x2 = range_min_0 + (f[i-2]/f[i-1])*(range_min_1-range_min_0);}              
                }              
            }       

            return (range_min_0 + range_min_1) / 2;
     }
```

Comment: You need to clarify your question and explain what errors you are getting, so we can help.

Comment: "*I encountered some errors*" such as?

Comment: The only mistake I have received so far is the wrong answer) and i don`t understand why.

Comment: Please provide a test case and tell if you have received any errors during compilation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace

```
int[] f = new int[j];
```

with

```
double[] f = new double[j];
```

The integer division truncates the fractional part e.g.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int x = 3, y = 4;
        System.out.println(x / y);
    }
}
```

**outputs,**

```
0
```

whereas

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        double x = 3, y = 4;
        System.out.println(x / y);
    }
}
```

**outputs,**

```
0.75
```

Answer (score 1):

The mixture of double and integer arithmetic looks suspicious. Specifically, `(f[i-2]/f[i])` means integer division, see [Java Language and Virtual Machine Specifications, 15.17. Multiplicative Operators](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se11/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.17). This means that the result is rounded down.